# Beautifulsoup: reference in a previous row in an iteration

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've been working during last days in a web scraping about this web: https://www.resultados-futbol.com/primera_division_femenina2020/grupo1/jornada6 I've been receiving an amazing help here and I'm very close to get my goal.

I want to get diferents elements of the web to create a dataframe. To extract these elements, I created a loop but that itirates the table and it takes some results. The problem is in cases the result is 0-0 I would like to append to my dictionary a value 'no gol' in 'first goal' and in 'goal minute'. The text of 0-0 is in a different tr than the information of 'first goals' and 'minutes' and then I don't know how to do it properly.

I've done this loop creating a variable 'details' where is the info for 'first goal' and 'minute' of the first event of each match (it's the only one I want). The problem is the loop is only reading the first event of the first game and I get the info of goals and minutes only repeatedly.

This is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://www.resultados-futbol.com/primera_division_femenina2020/grupo1/jornada6'
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

data = []

for row in soup.select('tr.vevent .rstd'):
    teams = row.select_one('.summary').get_text().split(' - ')
    score = row.select_one('.clase').get_text()
    details = soup.select_one('tr.vevent + tr.league-match-events')
    minute = details.select_one('.lme-minute').get_text()
    gol = details.select_one('.url').get_text()
    primergol.append(gol if score != "0-0" else "No gol")
    
    data.append({
        'team1': teams[0],
        'team2':teams[1],
        'score': score,
        'first goal': gol if score != "0-0" else "No gol",
        'first minute': minute if score != "0-0" else "No min"
    })
```

And this is the result in 'data'. As you can see, in all the games the info for first goal and minute is from the first game and not the respective one... but in the 0-0 match, where is correct:

```
[{'team1': 'Athletic Fem',
  'team2': 'Real Betis Fem',
  'score': '2-1',
  'first goal': '1-0',
  'first minute': "3'"},
 {'team1': 'Sporting Huelva Fem',
  'team2': 'Deportivo Abanca Fem',
  'score': '0-1',
  'first goal': '1-0',
  'first minute': "3'"},
 {'team1': 'UDG Tenerife Fem',
  'team2': 'Real Sociedad Fem',
  'score': '0-0',
  'first goal': 'No gol',
  'first minute': 'No min'},
 {'team1': 'Atlético Fem',
  'team2': 'Madrid CFF Fem',
  'score': '1-0',
  'first goal': '1-0',
  'first minute': "3'"},
 {'team1': 'Real Madrid Fem',
  'team2': 'Levante Fem',
  'score': '0-3',
  'first goal': '1-0',
  'first minute': "3'"},
 {'team1': 'Sevilla FC Fem',
  'team2': 'Espanyol Fem',
  'score': '4-0',
  'first goal': '1-0',
  'first minute': "3'"},
 {'team1': 'Rayo Vallecano Fem',
  'team2': 'Valencia Fem',
  'score': '3-2',
  'first goal': '1-0',
  'first minute': "3'"},
 {'team1': 'Barcelona Fem',
  'team2': 'Logroño Fem',
  'score': '5-0',
  'first goal': '1-0',
  'first minute': "3'"}]
```

I'm missing something about including the first event row in each match for capturing the data, but I don't know what exactly. Any help here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different solutions you can use to solve this issue.

### Solution#1

Very straight forward you can use `row.findNext('tr')` to get the next `<tr>`

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://www.resultados-futbol.com/primera_division_femenina2020/grupo1/jornada6'
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

data = []

for i, row in enumerate(soup.select('tr.vevent .rstd')):
    teams = row.select_one('.summary').get_text().split(' - ')
    score = row.select_one('.clase').get_text()
    details = row.findNext('tr')
    minute = details.select_one('.lme-minute').get_text()
    gol = details.select_one('.url').get_text() if score != "0-0" else "No gol"

    data.append({
        'team1': teams[0],
        'team2':teams[1],
        'score': score,
        'first goal': gol if score != "0-0" else "No gol",
        'first minute': minute if score != "0-0" else "No min"
    })

data
```

### Solution#2

Use the `data-match` attribute as reference to get the next `<tr>`

```
match = row.select_one('[data-match]')['data-match']
details = soup.select_one('tr[data-match="'+match+'"]')
```

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://www.resultados-futbol.com/primera_division_femenina2020/grupo1/jornada6'
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

data = []

for row in soup.select('tr.vevent'):
    match = row.select_one('[data-match]')['data-match']
    teams = row.select_one('.rstd .summary').get_text().split(' - ')
    score = row.select_one('.rstd .clase').get_text()
    details = soup.select_one('tr[data-match="'+match+'"]')
    minute = details.select_one('.lme-minute').get_text()
    gol = details.select_one('.url').get_text() if score != "0-0" else "No gol"

    data.append({
        'team1': teams[0],
        'team2':teams[1],
        'score': score,
        'first goal': gol if score != "0-0" else "No gol",
        'first minute': minute if score != "0-0" else "No min"
    })

data
```

Comment: They work perfect, both. Thank you again! I didn't know any of the solutions so it's very interesting keep learning :)